# Excel XLOOKUP searching first 8 characters of a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good evening all,

I want to do a xlookup() but the two columns do not always have the exact same values. However, the first 8 characters would always match in both columns. For example the value I wish to look up is "00123456 - Nice Salad". The data I wish to search in sits in Column A with value to return in Column B.

[image]

I know I can use the left() function on the value to lookup but I am unsure how best to search against just the first 8 characters in column A. I would like the formula to return the "6" from column B in this example.

I hope this all makes sense and any help is appreciated.

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: `=XLOOKUP("00123456*",A:A,B:B,"",2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XLOOKUP()` with wildcard `match_mode` will be best approach in this case and @Scott Craner already shown in comment how to use it.

```
=XLOOKUP("00123456*",A:A,B:B,,2)
```

Alternatively you can use `FILTER()` function in this way.

```
=FILTER(B:B,LEFT(A:A,8)="00123456")
```

Also `INDEX()/MATCH()` will work but lower performance.

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("00123456",LEFT(A:A,8),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thumbs up for sharing a 3 paths in 1 go. Legend. /(^-^)